# Inserting element into DOM instead of appending using dart:html

Tags: dart

The base `Element` object in dart:html has a property `elements` which is an implementation of `List<E>`.  The `add` method appends elements to the DOM.  I would like to prepend or insert an element into the DOM.  None of the insert methods in `ElementList` are implemented.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So lets say you have this HTML snippet:

```
<body>
    <div id='test'></div>
</body>
```

You can do this to insert an element before the div:

```
// Get the sibling that we want to insert before.
final el = query('#test');

// From the parent element, we call insertBefore, referencing the
// sibling that we want to insert the new element before.
document.body.insertBefore(new Element.tag('p'), el);
```

Now your HTML will be:

```
<body>
    <p></p>
    <div id='test'></div>
</body>
```

Comment: You are technically correct - the best kind of correct, but it'd sure be nice if the List implementation used for elements did this for us.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to John's Answer. You can also use the syntax:

```
final el = query('#test');

// If you want an element
el.insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', new Element.tag('p'));
// If you want to insert HTML tags
el.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<p>Hello</p>');
// Insert just text
el.insertAdjacentText('beforebegin', 'Hello there');
```

You can use positional arguments: *beforebegin*, *afterbegin*, *beforeend*, *afterend* Which will place it before the beginning of the other element, just inside the beginning of the element, just inside the end of the element, or just outside the end of the element, respectively.

Comment: Good addition Matt. :)  Personal pref for me - I like to stay strongly-typed as much as possible, so if I chose your route, I'd probably make an enum for the strings (maybe the dart:HTML API should already have this? Patch!) ;)

Comment: For me, similar to http://dartbug.com/3685 , I like the idea of adding convenience wrappers for this.